# Extracting .mbtiles exported by TileMill using mb-util

Tags: mapbox, tilemill, mbtiles, utfgrids

I'm using TileMill to export data to .mbtiles format. Then when I'm extracting these mbtiles using mb-util, only tiles are being extracted and no utfgrid files in json format.

I've tried

```
mb-util ./test.mbtiles ./test
```

and

```
mb-util --grid_callback="" ./test.mbtiles ./test
```

I guess mb-util is not the problem, as when I'm converting a .mbtiles file from the mb-util/test/data directory I do get json grid files aswell. So my guess would be that something is going wrong when exporting from TileMill. I've tried it with my own projects, but also with some default TileMill projects. In both cases PNG's are returned perfectly by mb-util but no UTFGRID.

What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution: in TileMill you'll have to define which layer you should use for interaction data, and specify the content to be shown on interactions. Once this is specified you can test in preview mode, if information shows up when you hover over the map it's good. Then you can export as .mbtiles, and mb-util will generate an utfgrid aswell.

Here's some more information:
[Tilemill project gitub.](http://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/tooltips/)